# How can I read a sh file while it is working but deleted?

Tags: command-line, bash

In an interview they asked me this question.

There was an sh file that is already running, but it has been deleted since starting the execution.

They want me to find the process and read the file.

I managed to find the process with

```
ps -ef | grep test.sh
```

and tried to read it by using

```
cat /proc/PID/cmdline test.sh
```

but it says

```
no such file or directory
```

I didn't know what I should do next so I had to skip this.

Maybe it was an easy question but that was really a good question for me and I really want to know the answer. Can you guys help?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
tail -c +0 -f /proc/{pid}/fd/{fd} > /tmp/file
```

where {pid} is the id of your process and `/tmp/file` will have its contents. Use another location and name if you want to preserve it.

- {pid} is the id of the process.
- {fd} is the file descriptor. `lsof` should show the fd. `lsof` is likely also going to show "deleted" on the line so you can `grep` that too. `lsof -nP +L1` will list all files with less than 1 link, a file deleted will have 0. Add a `| grep {pid}` to search for just your PID.
- from dessert: `lsof -p 22664 | sed -E '$!d;s/.*\s([0-9]+)[a-z]\s.*/\1/'` to just get the fd.
- from comments: you can use `less`, `cat` or `cp` too. I grew up on `tail` :)

Comment: "I grew up on tail!" A valuable insight for anyone having to do anything with *x.